# How to avoid breaking old code when updating classes shared amongst many apps

Tags: interface, frameworks, refactoring, version, package

With time I started using the same "framework" I built myself for many projects, but I'm in the process of refactoring a lot of it now. I will have to break the interface of many classes (changing return types, poor naming, functions that modified their input argument, some have nasty side effects...), and my older programs are obviously relying on them.

My question is: how do you make such big changes *and* keep older code working? Start making "version" folders?

Or is it a bad practice to use classes across projects directly? (e.g. a custom Math class, and everyone accesses the same *file*)

Answer (score 0):

If you meant actual interfaces:
As far as I know, you should try to avoid changing interfaces as much as possible. They're a contract and as such are set in stone. If you ever want to add or change something, you could overwrite it and add the new method to the subInterface.

In general:
I'd keep all the old methods, but deprecate them and rewire their functionality to your new overloads.